# Name for a person who is always trying to beat the system?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Someone I know is always finding a way to beat the system, for example:

Getting fake records to get his children into college, contacting people in the system to find him a way to bypass waiting for official papers, etc.

A word like conman or scammer would be used for someone who actually drafts fake records, not the one who orders them. What would you call the person who frequently buys forged documents?

Comment: Hmmm you would call him a fixer or operator if he did this on behalf of others. In some environs, apparently routine, legitimate things are so hard to do that you would call your subject "a citizen".

Comment: "A word like conman or scammer would be used for someone who actually drafts fake records, not the one who orders them"   Says who?

Comment: The person who creates fakes is a forger. The person who uses fakes is a scammer or conman (con artist).

Comment: Actually, someone who uses fake documents is an impersonator.  A good conman can do you out of your money with nothing but a smile and a story.

Comment: Your question has two different types of behavior in it. It's like asking, "what's a word to describe a person who likes to set fire to buildings and also steal small things at the store."  Not only are they an arsonist but they are also a kleptomaniac.  If they were a teen you would call them a juvenile delinquent, an adult a career criminal.  In your example, hustler is the best choice because it embodies many kinds of behavior...not only bad.  Someone new at an office could be called a hustler.  You can also hustle up some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that is either a ***[hustler](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hustler)*** or a ***[fraud](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fraud)***.

> *Hustler*
>   noun
>   1. an enterprising person determined to succeed; go-getter.

---

> Definition of *fraud* in English:
>   noun
>   [MASS NOUN]
>
> 1 Wrongful or criminal deception intended to result in financial or personal gain:
>   *'he was convicted of fraud'*
>   [COUNT NOUN]: prosecutions for social security frauds
>
> 1.1 [COUNT NOUN] A person or thing intended to deceive others, typically by unjustifiably claiming or being credited with accomplishments or qualities:
>   *'mediums exposed as tricksters and frauds'*

References:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hustler
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fraud

Comment: fraud sounds closer to what I'm looking for, but looking at the examples in the reference you provided, it sounds as if fraud is used more often in the context where someone is caught by authorities and about to be prosecuted. For some reason I would use the word `cheat` to describe a fraud before he/she gets caught. What do you think?

Comment: @achabacha322 fraud has no implication regarding getting caught or not.  Neither does cheating.  Fraud is about deception and so requires a victim.  Cheating can be done against a set of rules.  No victim required.  You can cheat at solitaire.  Cheating wouldn't work, however, if the method of beating the system didn't break any rules.  That's called "gaming the system".  We call such people businessmen, lawyers, and politicians. =)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the connotation you'd prefer, consider:

> **irrepressible** - not able to be controlled or restrained. [G](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=irrepressible)
>
> **cheat** -  (tr) to escape or avoid (something unpleasant) by luck or cunning: to cheat death. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cheat)

It is possible to "beat the system" while playing by all it's rules.  You find a path to success that the creators of the system never envisioned and likely would never had allowed had they thought of it. This behavior is known as "gaming the system".